# HTML prevent step validation of number input

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input

Defining the step attribute of a number input allows to de- and increase the number by pushing the up and down buttons:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="100" step="10">
```

Unfortunately setting this attribute also enables the validation which means setting a value between two steps manually is not allowed anymore:

[image]

In my case this should be still allowed, without disabling the validation completely.
**So the step should be applied to the buttons but not to the validation.**
I've searched a lot but found no straight forward solution for it. [This blog post](https://css-tricks.com/form-validation-part-2-constraint-validation-api-javascript/) shows there are several different validation errors like *valueMissing*, *typeMismatch, ... provided. The issue here seems to lie at the *stepMismatch*.

Is there a way where the step is still applied for the up and down buttons, still allowing to enter values in between without the validation to fail? Maybe by preventing the *stepMismatch* to be set?

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to add buttons that changes values with JavaScript rather than using the default HTML input.
If you want the same aspect some css could help